# How can I extract Information from a symbol?

Tags: documentation, information-function

I have defined usage statements for a few symbols, e.g., `foo::usage="This is how to use foo";`

If I type `? foo` or `Information[foo]`, I get in return a nicely formated cell with the string information. However, the command returns Null:

```
t = Information[foo];
FullForm[t]
```

My question: How can I get the usage statement and store it in a new variables? I could of course do `foo::usage`, but let's say I have a list of symbols, `lst = {foo, fii};`, how could I map `#::usage`  to all these symbols?

Comment: `t=foo::usage` huh?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read it to the end. `(#::"usage")&/@lst` should work.

Comment: Quite surprisingly, this do work! Thanks!

Comment: I would prefer explicitly using `MessageName[]` for this: `MessageName[#, "usage"] & /@ {General, Sin}`.

Comment: Salut @J. M., indeed, I came to this same solution. Would you want to turn your comment into an anwer?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get the usage statement and store it in a new variables?

```
 var = Information[foo]["Usage"]
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me. Mathematica v. 10.0. I get in return ``Null[Usage]``